# Intuition behind Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[image]

What is an intuitive explanation for the fact that the remainder of a Taylor polynomial has this equivalency? Why is z necessarily between x and c? Why does such a value for z exist in the first place?

Comment: Can you understand intuitively how to answer your questions when $n=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For n = 0, it's applying the mean value theorem to f(x).
For n = 1, it's applying the mean value theorem to
f(c) + f'(c)(x - c).
And so to n.  So it's basically an elaborate MVT.

Comment: Please go into further detail